# WordPress Address (URL) setting interferes with Let's Encrypt's challenge

Tags: wordpress, apache2, lets-encrypt

My WordPress website sits behind an `apache2` server. The actual site is located under `/srv/www/<foldername>` and therefore I changed the WordPress url settings:

- WordPress Address (URL) : `https://personaldomain.com/foldername`
- Site Address (URL) : `https://personaldomain.com/`

When `certbot` tries to solve the challenge, it tries to access `https://personaldomain.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/hash` while the actual file is located under `https://personaldomain.com/foldername/.well-known/acme-challenge/hash`.

What is a simple way to solve this? I tried many different ways with `.htaccess` as suggested by similar questions but it did not work for me. For example these:

1. `RedirectMatch /.well-known/(.*)$ https://presonaldomain.com/foldername/.well-known/$1`
2. `RewriteBase /`
   `RewriteRule ^(.*).well-known/(.*)$ $1<foldername>/.well-known/$2 [R=301, L]`

do not work

Comment: Firstly, you check the normal index html page on which url is working on server after set the url on Site Address and Wordpress Address url

Comment: With the WordPress settings that I mention in the question, the website opens normally at `https://personaldomain.com` (desired behavior)

Comment: check with https://personaldomain.com/index.html this url - create the index.html and check again its working or not

Comment: If I create the file `index.html` inside the foler `/srv/www/<foldername>/index.html` and then I try to open https://personaldomain.com/index.html, it does not work

Comment: http://personaldomain.com/<foldername>/index.html - please try this

Comment: This works, as I am implying in the question

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that a workaround solution to this is to edit `/etc/letsencrypt/renewal/<mycertificate>.conf` and change the challenge folder from `/srv/www/<foldername>` to just `/srv/www`